# Same values on each request in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Need to get the same values on each request in my views file. Instead of getting them on every request, I used `before_request` function and added them to global dict:

```
options = {}
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    options['ip'] = request.remote_addr
    options['useragent'] = request.user_agent.string
```

Is it a good solution or not? What can you recommend?

Comment: Well I think it's a good way anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this is to use Flask's `g` object. You can read about this here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a very bad idea. Although the request is a thread-local, so you can access it everywhere, your `options` dict is not; it is not threadsafe, and will therefore be shared across all requests.

Comment: This dict contains config to interop with APIs with GET/POST requests and it is already shared across all requests. What about this particular case?

Comment: You're adding request-specific data to it now, though. That is not safe.